# Create custom Windows10 image

Tags: windows, windows-10, iso-image, disk-image

I would like to create an image that's a copy of my w10 installation, so I can later create a VM with it. I would like to have my VM startup with the same files and configuration in the same folders. Is it possible?
I would like to create it for later deploying it to Azure, having node.js installed along python3

Comment: You need a retail license for Windows 10 because OEM licenses cannot be moved. Once you have a physical computer, you can convert it to a virtual machine with Hyper-V  Disk2VHD.

Comment: Could I create a copy of the already existing Azure VM so I can create an exact copy of it? @John

Comment: I am not sure if you can create a real machine from a virtual machine.  I will look around.

Comment: There is no need to create a real machine, the original purpose of the question was to (on end) create a copy of my Azure VM so it can be later uploaded to another Azure as a VM, in order to deploy an app @John

Comment: Try:  http://woshub.com/clone-import-export-virtual-machines-hyper-v/  and see if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks, will do! Been looking for an article like this but couldn't find anything too good

Comment: @EduardoEiroaBallester - You should be able to just clone the Azure VM.  However, your question makes no mention of using Azure, that significantly changes your question.